# Validar formulario impidiendo el registro si ya está registrado - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, validación

Necesito resolver el siguiente envío de formularios con *PHP*. Actualmente el formulario puede ser enviado sin ningún tipo de comprobación.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Socios (CI,password,NOMBRE,APELLIDO,GENERO,FECHANACIMIENTO,DIRECCION,CP,CIUDAD,PAIS,CELULARA,CELULARB,EMAIL) VALUES ('$CI','$password','$NOMBRE','$APELLIDO','$GENERO','$FECHANACIMIENTO','$DIRECCION','$CP','$CIUDAD','$PAIS','$CELULARA','$CELULARB','$EMAIL')";  
MySQL_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' . MySQL_error());  

if(empty($_POST['register-user'])) {

   /* Form Required Field Validation */
   foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
      if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $error_message = "Todos los datos son obligatorios. All Fields are required";
        break;
      }
   }

   /* Password Matching Validation */
   if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']){ 
     $error_message = 'Las claves deben ser iguales. Passwords should be same<br>'; 
   }

   /* Email Validation */
   if(!isset($error_message)) {
       if (!filter_var($_POST['EMAIL'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         $error_message = "El email no es válido. Invalid Email Address";
       }
   }

   /* Validation to check if gender is selected */
   if(!isset($error_message)) {
     if(!isset($_POST["GENERO"])) {
       $error_message = " Todos los datos son obligatorios. All Fields are required";
     }
   }

   /* Validation to check if Terms and Conditions are accepted */
   if(!isset($error_message)) {
      if(!isset($_POST["terms"])) {
        $error_message = "Debe aceptar las condiciones del registro";
      }
   } 

}
```

El formulario va a registrar usuarios por su documento `$CI`, y necesito que en la validación se impida el registro si ya está registrado.

Comment: Debes añadir un query `SELECT` a tu comprobación para ver si alguien ya se ha registrado con la misma $CI

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar que un usuario existe o no debes crear un `SELECT` y crear una comprobacion a tu campo `CI` si el dato obtenido por tu formulario ya existe o no en la `Base de datos`.

*Un posible ejemplo:*

```
<?php

//Sentencia.
$sentencia = "SELECT CI FROM Socios WHERE CI='$CI' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($tu_conexion,$sentencia);
$existe = mysqli_num_rows($query);//si encuentra un registro, es decir, usuario existe, su valor sera 1 en caso contrario es 0 (NULL).

//Comprobamos si existe usuario.
if ($existe===1) {
    $error_message = "El usuario ya existe.";
    break;
}

?>
```

> `MySQL*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

Para evitar la [inyeccion SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php), te aconsejo utilizar [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) o [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php).